# Creating a 1bpp (bit per pixel) Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

Ok so been racking my brain on this one all day.  Trying to figure out how I can convert a Bitmap from canvas to a 1bpp (bit per pixel) Bitmap file in Android and physically save it as such.

So far I've iterated through the bitmap and created an int[] of the resulting pixel values as 1s or 0s.  However, my next question is what do I do with that?

What I tried to do was something like

```
        int[] bits = // populated earlier

        byte[] bmp = new byte[bits.length / 8];

        int byteindex = 0;
        int bitindex = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<bits.length; i++) {
            if (bits[i] == 1)
                // set to 1
            else
                // set to 0
            if (bitindex++ == 8) {
                bitindex = 0;
                byteindex++;
            }
        }

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/dynbmp.bmp");
        out.write(bmp);
        out.close();
```

I get a file out of it but it's obviously not a valid bmp file.  Who knows what it is.  You'll have to forgive me for my lack of bit-byte and imaging knowledge, but where am I screwing up?  Do I the idea completely wrong? Am I missing some header info or something?

Comment: You've the Android side covered.  Now, read about the BMP file structure, and reproduce it for your data.  It's not just a mess of bytes in a file.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing several things. It's a little bit more complicated... Look here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: hm I think I've frazzled my brain a bit and just hoped it would magically work.  I'll have to read it up a bit.